# Don't Show Hamburger Menu in WordPress with WooCommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce, responsive, hamburger-menu, storefront

we're programming a webshop using WordPress and Woocommerce. (http://staightgang.com)
We want to show only the navbar not the Hamburger menu when in mobile view. Looked through the whole css but didn't find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, no dedicated code has been written, had no idea, where to Start 

Answer (score 0):

In the mobile view, `.handheld-navigation` class has an overflow property which is set as hidden, so you may try unsetting the overflow.

```
.handheld-navigation {
    overflow: unset !important;
}
```

Now, you no longer need the menu button, so simply hide it.

```
button.menu-toggle {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you want your menu nav menu items to display horizontally, you can try with the following CSS

```
.handheld-navigation ul.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea, how to delete the links from the insta-feed-plugin at /gang so that it only shows non-clickable Photos? I tried adding additional css and Java Script,  but it didn't work either way...